# Not able to login using python request module

Tags: python, python-2.7, cookies, authentication, python-requests

My form structure is:

```
<POST https://www.lumosity.com/authentication application/x-www-form-urlencoded
<HiddenControl(utf8=✓) (readonly)>
<HiddenControl(authenticity_token=xMELAlMu5kqxE23RdvRj+UjyF+bXVynw9AgHIc2j69Q=) (readonly)>
<HiddenControl(screen_resolution=) (readonly)>
<HiddenControl(activation_code=) (readonly)>
<HiddenControl(redirect_uri=) (readonly)>
<TextControl(user[login]=)>
<PasswordControl(user[password]=)>
<SubmitControl(commit=Log In) (readonly)>
<SubmitButtonControl(<None>=) (readonly)>
<CheckboxControl(persistent_login=[*1])>>
```

My code for logging in is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

payload = {
   'user[login]'    : '***@gmail.com',
   'user[password]' : '******'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    m = s.get('https://www.lumosity.com/login',headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})        
    t = s.post('https://www.lumosity.com/login',data = payload)
    r = s.get('http://www.lumosity.com/app/v4/dashboard')
```

Currently I am not using "authenticity token" for logging in. *Is it required*?

1. If so, how do I access it?
2. Do *all* the parameters in the form structure need to be passed through "payload",
   even though some are empty?
3. Once I have a successful login, what is the one thing I should print to validate that it was successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd *expect* the `authenticity_token` field to be required, yes. I say *expect* because it really depends on the server exactly what it'll expect. That server is a black box, and we cannot see into it how it'll behave, but the same token is also associated with the name `csrf-token` in a `<meta>` tag at the top, so it's used as Cross-Site Forgery protection; I'd expect the token to be required in that case.

And, if login works with your browser and your browser sends that information, best try to mimic that as close as you can.

You'd have to parse out the result of the `m` response to the value. You could use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(m.content)
token = soup.select('input[name="authenticity_token"]')[0]['value']
```

Wether or not the login will work without the other fields is a question of trial and error.

You will need to adjust *where you POST to* however; the form at `/login` posts to `/authentication`. The `/login` URL most likely will just return the form again, *or* return a 405 Method Not Allowed error.

You'll know you have been successful when the response from the `s.post()` call is not the login form again; e.g. when you have been redirected to a *different* page.

You can automate form handling with a tool like [robobrowser](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser); it uses `requests` and BeautifulSoup together to do the same as above *and* handle those hidden fields for you:

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)
browser.open('https://www.lumosity.com/login')
form = browser.get_form()
form['user[login]'].value = '***@gmail.com'
form['user[password'].value = '******'
browser.submit_form(form)
```